# Developing iOS apps on Mac 10.5.8

Tags: ios, xcode

I have searched through mac dev center for iOS SDK compatible with 10.5.8, but couldn't find the sdk. I have a apple id (but have not yet joined the developer program). I found xcode 3.2 but it says it needs Mac 10.6. Is it possible to develop ipad/iphone apps on Mac 10.5 and if so, how? (Btw, I do understand it is only $29 to upgrade to 10.6 but not ready to take the plunge right now)

Thank you for the answers.
Joseph

Comment: You can take the plunge easily by installing snow leopard on an external drive and using that for development purposes. The current iOS SDK requires Snow Leopard so you will be very handicapped. This setup will be handy when it's time to move to Lion.

Comment: This site isn't for Apple Development, as per the FAQs. I've migrated your question to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

Apple's current position is the following:

Xcode 3.2 requires an Intel-based Mac running Mac OS X Snow Leopard version 10.6.6 or later.

This is from the Xcode 3.2.6 Readme.

When iOS 4.0 was released, it required 10.6.2 as per this page.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iPhoneSDK-4_0/_index.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009763

However, if you can locate version 3.1.4, it worked with 10.5 and iPhone OS 3 (if you have the SDK). It even ran on PowerPC systems. But I don't believe it works with the iOS versions 4+ (based on the references above).

Comment: However, Apple no longer accepts applications for the App Store that are built against anything earlier than the iOS 4.0 SDK.  From the [June 29, 2010 new update](http://developer.apple.com/news/): "All new applications and updates to existing applications must be built with iPhone SDK 4. In addition, the App Store will no longer support applications that target iOS 2.x."  You'll still be able to develop applications for use on your own 3.x devices, but not for submission to the App Store.