# install iOS 7 sdk in OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I'd like to start programming apps for iphones and ipads so a friend borrowed me an old MacBook as a starting point.
The fact is that it is running OS X Leopard (10.5.8).
When downloading xcode, the only available version is 3.1.4 and there are no SDKs in it --> From this post [develop app in 10.5.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484409/developing-ios-apps-on-mac-10-5-8) I realized there is no way for adding sdks.

So I was thinking to buy OS X Snow Leopard in order to have at least the possibility to have SDK 4.
But after reading some others discussion I discovered that Apple will not approve apps with lower SDKs than iOS 7. What does it mean? That if I use SDK 4 and some methods are deprecated in 7, they will not accept the app? Or there is a flag somewhere that shows compatibility?

In this last case, so I have to set the sdk7 somewhere, if I buy Snow Leopard it will be possible to add iOS 7 SDK to its xcode version (3.2.6)?

Comment: Is the machine too old for a newer OS than 10.6, or is there another reason to go for an older OS?

Comment: according to this page: https://www.apple.com/it/osx/how-to-upgrade/ it is too old as it a MacBook but in white plastic :(

Comment: if it's useful, from the check of the serial number I get    MB 13.3/2.1/2x512MB/120/SD   and googling it I found that it should be 2008 .. but in plastic

Comment: Yep, sounds like you're struck with Snow Leopard... I'm unaware of any way to develop an app on Snow Leopard that will be allowed in the IOS app store nowadays.